# How to share image through WhatsApp?

Tags: image, whatsapp

I'm using this code, but it's not working, how can it fit it?
Anyone help? Thanks!

```
UIImage  *iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home01-A01.png"];

NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

_documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];

_documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";

_documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

[_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? Do you get an error? What do you expect, and what do you get instead?

Comment: it not get error, but i Press whatsapp icon, the app with quit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can share your file on WhatsApp using UIDocumentationView Controller, do the following to achieve the same,

**In your viewcontroller.h file**,

- add Delegate for

> UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

- declare UIDocumentInteractionController object like this

> UIDocumentInteractionController *controller;

**In your viewcontroller.m file**,

- add following Delegate methos for UIDocumentationView controller to track the status for success and failure

  ## pragma mark - Delegate Methods

  ```
  - (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {

     return  self;
  }    
  - (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

     NSLog(@"Starting to send this puppy to %@", application);
  }

  - (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

     NSLog(@"We're done sending the document.");
  }
  ```

  - add following code to share your file,

    ```
    -(void)openDocument {
        // here's a URL from our bundle
        NSURL *documentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"chat" withExtension:@"png”];// You can set your filename and extention here

        // pass it to our document interaction controller
        controller = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.URL = documentURL;

        // present the preview
        [controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }
    ```

> **Note:** the URL that you specify needs to be local.
>
> The goal of the `UIDocumentInteractionController` is to share (local) documents
>   between applications.if your file is not stored locally then you can
>   achive this by storing the file in temp or local caching directory then accessing it from the
>   main bundle.